# JavaScript - target a specific element, knowing only its class

Tags: javascript, html

I am wondering how to target a specific element, knowing only its class.

I want to click the `.editPrice` button and only showing the `.popupPriceContainer` next to the button and not all of them.

The close button works fine since it is a child of the element I want to hide and I can easily target it with `parentNode`.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jwLf4smu/1/

And Here a runnable snippet:

```js
//CLOSE POPUP PRICE CONTAINER

//create variable from pop up close buttons
const popupClose = document.getElementsByClassName('popupClose');

//set price edit container to display none
Array.from(popupClose).forEach((popupClose) => {
  popupClose.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // 2x .parentNode to select the outer wrapper
    popupClose.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "none";
  });
});


//OPEN POPUP PRICE CONTAINER

//create variable for all edit price buttons and price edit pop up container
const popupEditPrice = document.getElementsByClassName('editPrice');
const priceContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('popupPriceContainer');

//show price edit box
Array.from(popupEditPrice).forEach((popupEditPrice) => {
  popupEditPrice.addEventListener('click', () => {

    Array.from(priceContainer).forEach((priceContainer) => {
      priceContainer.style.display = "block";
    });

  });
});
```

```css
#serviceList .position {
  margin-top: 16px;
}

.popupPriceContainer {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<section id="serviceList" class="items">

  <div class="position">
    <button type="button" class="editPrice">Edit price</button>

    <div class="item">
      Service 1
    </div>

    <div class="price">
      <span class="amount" id="priceElement">100</span>
    </div>

    <div class="popupPriceContainer">
      <div class="popupPriceInner">
        <input type="number" placeholder="100,00" class="priceInput">
        <button value="Set Value" class="submbitPrice popupClose">Submit</button>
        <button class="popupClose">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="position">
    <button type="button" class="editPrice">Edit price</button>

    <div class="item">
      Service 2
    </div>

    <div class="price">
      <span class="amount">1000</span>
    </div>

    <div class="popupPriceContainer">
      <div class="popupPriceInner">
        <input type="number" placeholder="100,00" class="priceInput">
        <button value="Set Value" class="submbitPrice popupClose">Submit</button>
        <button class="popupClose">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="position">
    <button type="button" class="editPrice">Edit price</button>

    <div class="item">
      Service 3
    </div>

    <div class="price">
      <span class="amount">240</span>
    </div>

    <div class="popupPriceContainer">
      <div class="popupPriceInner">
        <input type="number" placeholder="100,00" class="priceInput">
        <button value="Set Value" class="submbitPrice popupClose">Submit</button>
        <button class="popupClose">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Delegate to the main static container and use e.target and relative addressing: `e.target.closest('.popupPriceContainer')`

Comment: dont use `getElementsByClassName` anymore. In 2021 you should use `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

prefer to use a class:

```css
.noDisplay {
  display: none;
  }
```

then use `[element].classList` / `.add()` or `.remove()` methods

full code:

```js
const
  editBtns  = document.querySelectorAll('button.editPrice')
, closeBtns = document.querySelectorAll('button.popupClose')
  ;
editBtns.forEach(btn=>
  {
  btn.onclick = ({target}) =>  // get only target object in event 
    {
    target.closest('div.position').querySelector('.popupPriceContainer').classList.remove('noDisplay')
    }
  })
closeBtns.forEach(btn=>
  {
  btn.onclick = ({target}) =>  // get only target object in event 
    {
    let 
      div_position            = target.closest('div.position')
      box_popupPriceContainer = div_position.querySelector('.popupPriceContainer')
    , price_El                = box_popupPriceContainer.querySelector('input.priceInput')
    , actual_amount_el        = div_position.querySelector('span.amount')
      ;
    if (target.matches('.submbitPrice'))
      {
      // do submit price stuff
      let priceVal = parseInt( price_El.value.replace(/\D/g, ''),10) || 0;  // otherwise use parseFloat()
 
      price_El.value = priceVal;
      actual_amount_el.textContent = priceVal

      // do submit price  other stuff 
      }
    // else price_El.value = actual_amount_el.textContent 

    box_popupPriceContainer.classList.add('noDisplay')
    }
  })
```

```css
#serviceList .position {
  margin-top: 16px;
  }
.noDisplay {
  display: none;
  }
```

```html
<section id="serviceList" class="items">

  <div class="position">
    <button type="button" class="editPrice">Edit price</button>

    <div class="item">
      Service 1
    </div>

    <div class="price">
      <span class="amount" id="priceElement">100</span>
    </div>

    <div class="popupPriceContainer noDisplay">
      <div class="popupPriceInner">
        <input type="number" placeholder="100,00" class="priceInput">
        <button value="Set Value" class="submbitPrice popupClose">Submit</button>
        <button class="popupClose">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="position">
    <button type="button" class="editPrice">Edit price</button>

    <div class="item">
      Service 2
    </div>

    <div class="price">
      <span class="amount">1000</span>
    </div>

    <div class="popupPriceContainer noDisplay">
      <div class="popupPriceInner">
        <input type="number" placeholder="100,00" class="priceInput">
        <button value="Set Value" class="submbitPrice popupClose">Submit</button>
        <button class="popupClose">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="position">
    <button type="button" class="editPrice">Edit price</button>

    <div class="item">
      Service 3
    </div>

    <div class="price">
      <span class="amount">240</span>
    </div>

    <div class="popupPriceContainer noDisplay">
      <div class="popupPriceInner">
        <input type="number" placeholder="100,00" class="priceInput">
        <button value="Set Value" class="submbitPrice popupClose">Submit</button>
        <button class="popupClose">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</section>
```

> but it should be better to use a delegate method way
> (get the global click over the section, then determine wich button is clicked)
> I also changed your Edit price / Close Price method, to put them on the same button, it is more ergonomic

code:

```js
document.querySelector('#serviceList').onclick = ({target}) =>  // get only target object in event 
  {
  if (!target.matches('button.editPrice, button.submbitPrice')) return // ignore click elsewhere
 
  let 
    div_position            = target.closest('div.position')
  , price_El                = div_position.querySelector('input.priceInput')
  , actual_amount_el        = div_position.querySelector('span.amount')
    ;
  if (target.matches('button.editPrice'))
    {
    target.textContent = div_position.classList.toggle('noPriceEdit') ? 'Edit price' : 'Close edit'
    }
  else // button.submbitPrice stuff
    {
    let priceVal = parseFloat( price_El.value) || 0;  
    price_El.value = actual_amount_el.textContent = priceVal.toFixed(2)
 
    div_position.classList.add('noPriceEdit')
    div_position.querySelector('button.editPrice').textContent = 'Edit price'
    }
  }
```

```css
#serviceList .position {
  margin-top: 16px;
  }
div.position.noPriceEdit > div.popupPriceContainer {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section id="serviceList" class="items">
  <div class="position noPriceEdit">
    <button type="button" class="editPrice">Edit price</button>
    <div class="item">Service 1</div>
    <div class="price"><span class="amount" id="priceElement">100</span></div>
    <div class="popupPriceContainer noDisplay">
      <div class="popupPriceInner">
        <input type="number" placeholder="100,00" class="priceInput">
        <button value="Set Value" class="submbitPrice">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="position noPriceEdit">
    <button type="button" class="editPrice">Edit price</button>
    <div class="item">Service 2</div>
    <div class="price"><span class="amount">1000</span></div>
    <div class="popupPriceContainer noDisplay">
      <div class="popupPriceInner">
        <input type="number" placeholder="100,00" class="priceInput">
        <button value="Set Value" class="submbitPrice">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="position noPriceEdit">
    <button type="button" class="editPrice">Edit price</button>
    <div class="item">Service 3</div>
    <div class="price"><span class="amount">240</span></div>
    <div class="popupPriceContainer noDisplay">
      <div class="popupPriceInner">
        <input type="number" placeholder="100,00" class="priceInput">
        <button value="Set Value" class="submbitPrice">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please [delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69244117/295783)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and for your great answer and for already incorporating the price Submit! @MisterJojo

Answer (score 1):

Delegate to the main static container and use e.target and relative addressing: `e.target.closest('.popupPriceContainer')`

Note I add and remove a class `.hide`

```js
document.getElementById('serviceList').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains('popupClose')) {
    const parent = tgt.closest('.popupPriceContainer')
    parent.classList.add('hide')
  }
  if (tgt.classList.contains('editPrice')) {
    const parent = tgt.closest('.position')
    parent.querySelector('.popupPriceContainer').classList.remove('hide')
  }
})
```

```css
#serviceList .position {
  margin-top: 16px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section id="serviceList" class="items">

  <div class="position">
    <button type="button" class="editPrice">Edit price</button>

    <div class="item">
      Service 1
    </div>

    <div class="price">
      <span class="amount" id="priceElement">100</span>
    </div>

    <div class="popupPriceContainer hide">
      <div class="popupPriceInner">
        <input type="number" placeholder="100,00" class="priceInput">
        <button value="Set Value" class="submbitPrice popupClose">Submit</button>
        <button class="popupClose">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="position">
    <button type="button" class="editPrice">Edit price</button>

    <div class="item">
      Service 2
    </div>

    <div class="price">
      <span class="amount">1000</span>
    </div>

    <div class="popupPriceContainer hide">
      <div class="popupPriceInner">
        <input type="number" placeholder="100,00" class="priceInput">
        <button value="Set Value" class="submbitPrice popupClose">Submit</button>
        <button class="popupClose">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="position">
    <button type="button" class="editPrice">Edit price</button>

    <div class="item">
      Service 3
    </div>

    <div class="price">
      <span class="amount">240</span>
    </div>

    <div class="popupPriceContainer hide">
      <div class="popupPriceInner">
        <input type="number" placeholder="100,00" class="priceInput">
        <button value="Set Value" class="submbitPrice popupClose">Submit</button>
        <button class="popupClose">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this clean and short approach! Wish I could accept two answers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the following code:

```
 popupEditPrice.addEventListener('click', () => {

     Array.from(priceContainer).forEach((priceContainer) => {
         priceContainer.style.display = "block";
     });

 });
```

When the "edit price" button is clicked the `forEach` in the above code searches for  all price containers & shows them.

Each "edit price" button & its corresponding "price container" is inside a `<div class="position">`.

1. Declare an event paramenter for the click listener
2. Get a reference to the clicked price button using `event.currentTarget`
3. Get a reference to the corresponding `.position` using [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method
4. Find the `.popupPriceContainer` inside the `div.position` using [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element/querySelector)
5. Show the `.popupPriceContainer` using `display block`.